# PS - Capture returned error codes from quser query

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Powershell script using PS 5:

Running a script to loop through all the servers in AD, and grab the sessionID if a specified user is has a login session on that server.  I'm using quser to do so:

```
 $sessionID = ((quser /server:$server | ? { $_ -match $username } ) -split ' +')[2]
```

There are a few servers that are returning:

```
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
```

I'm not worried about the reason for this error (It's an account permissions issue--not the topic for this question)

What I ***do*** need is to capture when this happens; however, it's not caught in a try/catch even when using -ErrorAction Stop, and if I check `$?` it returns True. I've tried testing $? and putting -ErrorAction Stop at various points of the pipeline, even reducing it to just the /quser query with out trying to strip out the sessionID:`$sessionID = quser /server:$server -ErrorAction Stop`

That error output is also not getting stored in $SessionID so I can't check it there.

How can I capture this error output so that I can place it in the status/logging output file created elsewhere in the script?

Comment: so something like: `$quser = quser /server:$server 2>&1 | Out-File -FilePath C:\MyPath\here.txt`?

Comment: Quser is not a powershell command and therefore will not recognize -ErrorAction. Try setting $erroractionpreference = ‘Stop’ before the try/catch

Answer (score 1):

For external command errors, $LASTEXITCODE will be non-zero.  $? will be false too, but as soon as another powershell command or operator is run, $? gets set again.  Try/catch and erroraction have no effect on external commands.

```
$quser = quser /server:yahoo.com | ? { $_ -match 'joe' }
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.

$?
False

$LASTEXITCODE
1

$?
True
```

Even the parentheses changes $?.

```
$quser = (quser /server:yahoo.com | ? { $_ -match 'joe' })
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.

$?
True

$LASTEXITCODE
1
```

Here's a way to retain $?.

```
$quser = quser /server:yahoo.com | ? { $_ -match 'joe' } | % { (-split $_)[2] }
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.

$?
False

$LASTEXITCODE
1
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's because `$LASTEXITCODE` ran successfully. `$?` is for internal powershell use that'll capture if the previous command ran successfully or not.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That's a good point.  Even running $? twice would do it.